# Assign numbers to rows which a similar to the loop numbers in R

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping a site in R (rvest package) and I want to create in every parsed csv file a new column and 1) assign to numbers similar to my loop numbers or 2) create a new column and assign a special value (which I got using rvest nodes). I can assign these numbers if I **scrape** only one page, but that is not what I need. And the for loop works smoothly.

Here is my code with for loop

```
registered <- for (n in c(11:12)){     
  url_2019 <- 
paste0("https://www.cvk.gov.ua/pls/vnd2019/wp033pt001f01=919pf7331=", n 
,".html")
  results_2019 <- read_html(url_2019)%>% html_table(fill = TRUE)

results_2019[[6]]%>%as.data.frame

  #dir.create("registered_major_2019")
  file <- paste0("registered_major_2019/dist_", n, ".csv")
  if (!file.exists(file)) write.csv(results_2019[[6]], file, fileEncoding 
= "Windows-1251") 

Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

And I know to do it separately

```
url_2019 <- 

paste0("https://www.cvk.gov.ua/pls/vnd2019/wp033pt001f01=919pf7331=11
.html")
               
results_2019 <- read_html(url_2019)%>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
pfont <-  read_html(url_2019)%>% html_node("font")%>%html_text()
# This is actually what I need
results_2019a <- data.frame(results_2019[[6]], pfont)
```

But can't figure it out how to do it in for(). I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
registered <- for (n in c(11:12)){     
  url_2019 <- 
paste0("https://www.cvk.gov.ua/pls/vnd2019/wp033pt001f01=919pf7331=", n 
,".html")

results_2019 <- read_html(url_2019)%>% html_table(fill = TRUE)%>%data.frame()

pfont <-  read_html(url_2019)%>% html_node("font")%>%html_text()

  df <- data.frame(results_2019[[6]], pfont)

 #dir.create("registered_major_2019")
     file <- paste0("registered_major_2019/dist_", n, ".csv")
    if (!file.exists(file)) write.csv(df, file, fileEncoding = "Windows- 
 1251") 

  Sys.sleep(0.5)
 }
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? 
By the way, your third block of code creates a data frame already when generating `results_2019`. A step that you do not do above. As data frames have two dimensions, you should account for that in the subsetting. As you apparently only want to keep the sixth element you could add `.[[6]]` between `html_table(fill = TRUE)` and `data.frame()`. Subsequently, the new column containing pfont could e.g. be added via `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: @Chr Mutate works only when I scrap one page, but not in for()

Comment: Whether `mutate` works or not should be entirely unrelated to `for`. The reason for your code to fail lies in the differences between the three code chunks. Compare the center of your code line by line and you find the error.